# Detailtext is only showing in first tab

Tags: objective-c

Got the code but detailText is only showing in the first 'column' in case 0

code is under: cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
  if (indexPath.row == 0) {

        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"A";
    }

}    

 else if (indexPath.row == 1){

cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"B";

}

else if (indexPath.row == 2){

cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"C";

}

else if (indexPath.row == 3){

cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"D";

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an obvious right-brace mismatch, change your code to:

```
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"A";
}
else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"B";
...
```

You can shorten that to

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [@"ABCD" substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(indexPath.row,1)];
```

Comment: `characterAtIndex:` returns a `unichar`, not an `NSString`, so that won't work. You would use `substringWithRange:` in this case.